# Conditional sum in Neo4j Cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a Neo4j database of bank accounts and their incoming transfers. Each transfer occurs at some hour. There are 24 hourNodes representing each different hour (1,2,...,24). I need to know the total money transferred to each account for each hour, like this (yes, I really need 25 columns in the resulting table!):

```
accountName     totalH1   totalH2   ...   totalH24
My Account #1   19        50        ...   34
My Account #2   5         14        ...   99
...
```

This simple query:

```
MATCH (account)->(transfer)->(hourNode)
RETURN
  account.name,
  hourNode.hour,
  sum(transfer.amount)
```

gives results in a different format:

```
accountName     hour   total
My Account #1   1      19
My Account #1   2      50
...
My Account #1   24     34
My Account #2   1      5
...
```

I cannot change database structure. How would I write a query to return the data in the format described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know a way how to exactly create the output you've described, but we can easily get very close to that.

What you basically want is a row per name and a ordered list of sums. You can do that using a `WITH` that cares about ordering and a `collect` to build the list:

```
MATCH (account)->(transfer)->(hourNode)
WITH
  account.name as name,
  hourNode.hour as hour,
  sum(transfer.amount) as sum
ORDER BY name, hour
RETURN name, collect(hour) as hours, collect(sum) as sums
```

Comment: Thanks! To get exactly what I needed, I changed the RETURN part a little: RETURN name, collect(sum)[0] as totalH1, ..., collect(sum)[23] as totalH24